# Angular 6 Auth0 - global not defined

Tags: angular, auth0

Ive upgraded my app from angular 5 to angular 6. i get the following error now.

```
Uncaught ReferenceError: global is not defined
at Object../node_modules/auth0-lock/lib/utils/cdn_utils.js (cdn_utils.js:13)
```

> "angular2-jwt": "^0.2.3", "auth0-js": "^9.5.1", "auth0-lock":
>   "^11.6.1",

Answer (score 26, accepted):

There was a similar issue in [this angular thread](https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/issues/8160):

> On version 6 of Angular CLI we are removing the shim for `global` and
>   other node built-ins. You can read more about why this change was made
>   in [#9827](https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/issues/9827#issuecomment-369578814) (comment).
>
> **If you are using a library that assumes these globals are present, you
>   can try manually shimming it inside your `polyfills.ts` file:**
>
> `// Add global to window, assigning the value of window itself. 
>   (window as any).global = window;`

Adding the line should resolve your error.