# Upgrading to angular-6.x gives "Uncaught ReferenceError: global is not defined"

Tags: javascript, angular, angular-cli, angular6

I upgraded my project from angular-5.x to angular-6.x and it started giving the following error and even creation of dummy global variable does not work as given here [Angular 6 Auth0 - global not defined](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50209019/angular-6-auth0-global-not-defined)

The error is as follows:

```
Uncaught ReferenceError: global is not defined
    at Object../node_modules/has-binary2/index.js (index.js:10)
    at __webpack_require__ (bootstrap:81)
    at Object../node_modules/socket.io-parser/index.js (index.js:8)
    at __webpack_require__ (bootstrap:81)
    at Object../node_modules/socket.io-client/lib/index.js (index.js:7)
    at __webpack_require__ (bootstrap:81)
    at Object../src/app/app4pc/apiConnection/services/ApiConnectionServer.ts (auth.interceptor.ts:8)
    at __webpack_require__ (bootstrap:81)
    at Object../src/app/app4pc/apiConnection/toServer.module.ts (ApiConnectionServer.ts:11)
    at __webpack_require__ (bootstrap:81)
```

after resolving this I get following error:

```
Uncaught ReferenceError: process is not defined
    at Object../node_modules/process-nextick-args/index.js (index.js:3)
    at __webpack_require__ (bootstrap:81)
    at Object../node_modules/readable-stream/lib/_stream_readable.js (_stream_readable.js:26)
    at __webpack_require__ (bootstrap:81)
    at Object../node_modules/readable-stream/readable-browser.js (readable-browser.js:1)
    at __webpack_require__ (bootstrap:81)
    at Object../node_modules/simple-peer/index.js (index.js:7)
    at __webpack_require__ (bootstrap:81)
    at Object../src/app/util/services/call.services.ts (notification.service.ts:12)
    at __webpack_require__ (bootstrap:81)
```

And continues on and on.

Comment: Check your CLI version: https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/issues/8160

Comment: In case anyone faces that error wit ng 6 and AWS cognito, I've found a workaround, described here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/50377270/2398593

Answer (score 126, accepted):

Add following code in your starting page e.g. index.html

```js
var global = global || window;
var Buffer = Buffer || [];
var process = process || {
  env: { DEBUG: undefined },
  version: []
};
```

Example:

```html
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>Client</title>
  <base href="/">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="icon" type="image/x-icon" href="favicon.ico">
  <script>
    var global = global || window;
    var Buffer = Buffer || [];
    var process = process || {
      env: { DEBUG: undefined },
      version: []
    };
  </script>
</head>
<body>
  <app-root>
    <div class="loader"></div>
  </app-root>
</body>
</html>
```

Above will work on hybrid app (in Node environment) as well as in browser

> - for "Uncaught ReferenceError: global is not defined":
>
>   ```js
>   var global = global || window;
>   ```
> - for "Uncaught ReferenceError: Buffer is not defined":
>
>   ```js
>   var Buffer = Buffer || [];
>   ```
> - for "Uncaught ReferenceError: process is not defined":
>
>   ```js
>   var process = process || {
>     env: { DEBUG: undefined }
>   }
>   ```
> - for "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'slice' of undefined":
>
>   ```js
>   var process = process || {
>     env: { DEBUG: undefined },
>     version: []
>   };
>   ```

Comment: how to fix this error
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'slice' of undefined

Comment: It worked but can you explain the reason for this error and how this make it fixed?

Comment: Basically new angular environment, it expect these global variables which available in only node environment. So we made proxy for them.

Comment: If you defined process value as above then the app consists as server side app. It wont consider as web app. By default you will receive process.browser value.

Comment: This solution appears to break ASP.NET core SignalR currently.

Comment: For anyone coming here, do check the http client module being added is from @angular/common/http or from selenium-webdriver/http. selenium-webdriver/http also causes same issue.

Comment: Not working for: Node 10.15.0 Angular 8.3.23 Typescript 3.5.3

Comment: What issue is coming?

Answer (score 136):

Adding this line to `polyfills.ts` should resolve node global error

`(window as any).global = window;`

The solution was mentioned in this [angular-cli issue thred](https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/issues/9827#issuecomment-386154063)

Comment: Adding to polyfills.ts, as suggested in angular-cli, didn't resolve the issue for me.  It seems that some 3rd party library is attempting to access global BEFORE polyfills.ts is loaded (i.e., perhaps before angular is loaded?).  The only way I could get around the issue was to follow the accepted solution above by modifying my index.html page. :-(

Comment: If adding it _directly_ to polyfills.ts doesn't work, another way to still use this solution is to add a new file (called global-shim.ts, for example) and add the script in there, and then import the new file into polyfills.ts.  This solution was mentioned in this [angular-cli issue thread](https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/issues/8160#issuecomment-392716566)

Comment: Adding as an import to the polyfills.ts file as mentioned by @risingTide worked for me.

Comment: Adding that this issue came up for me after upgrading from a working Angular 11 to Angular 12. Lots of stuff must have changed under the hood... and booting out "global" must have been one of them. *I'm* not using it but someone must be looking for it.

Answer (score 8):

I use `HttpClient` and accidentally selected the default import which was `'selenium-webdriver/http'`

If your app.module.ts has `import { HttpClient } from 'selenium-webdriver/http';`

Update it to `import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';`

That fixed my issue.

Comment: Superb. It's the same issue for me. Did as you said and it worked. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 5):

adding this line into `pollyfills.ts` fixed my problem (just a workaround as @kemalbirinci said [here](https://github.com/swimlane/ngx-dnd/issues/81#issuecomment-399005701))

`(window as any).global = window;`

Answer (score 2):

In case, if your **target** is **node** in webpack (`target: 'node'`), because you want to fix `"Can't resolve 'fs'`. Then you're getting the following error `Fix: "Uncaught ReferenceError: global is not defined"` do it as follows `node: { global: true, fs: 'empty' }`. **Bonus**: if you got error `"Uncaught ReferenceError: exports is not defined".` simply add `libraryTarget: 'umd'`. The complete webpack config code is below.

```
const webpackConfig = {
  node: { global: true, fs: 'empty' }, // Fix: "Uncaught ReferenceError: global is not defined", and "Can't resolve 'fs'".
  output: {
    libraryTarget: 'umd' // Fix: "Uncaught ReferenceError: exports is not defined".
  }
};

module.exports = webpackConfig; // Export all custom Webpack configs.
```

Many solutions have been proposed here: https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/issues/8160

Answer (score 2):

Please be careful with using the top answer of adding the inline script to index.html. it will solve the immediate issue.  However, if you are using SignalR, this will generate this error:

Error: Error parsing handshake response: TypeError: Right-hand side of 'instanceof' is not callable
at HubConnection.push../node_modules/@microsoft/signalr/dist/esm/HubConnection.js.HubConnection.processHandshakeResponse

However, just defining global on its own will work and not break Signal R.

Answer (score 0):

In my case, socket.io entry was missing from `Package.JSON` file. Please check it and install it to the package.

Answer (score 0):

Adding the below lines in polyfills.ts worked fine for me after migrating to Angular v6.

```
(window as any).global = window;
global.Buffer = global.Buffer || require('buffer').Buffer;
global.process = require('process');
```

Answer taken from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60195988/4218672)

Answer (score -3):

I don't know if this will help anyone understand their issue, I just thought I would inform anyone reading this who got the global not defined error on the user side to check your browser and/or device settings for pages asking for your location. I had just been inside the chrome browsers site settings and turned the option for location from ask first to blocked. The very next page I visited, the main content a data tableau exhibited this error message, soon as I toggled location back to ask first in chrome site settings and refreshed the page it loaded without error.