# Buffer is not defined error after migrating to Angular 7

Tags: angular

I am migrating an Angular 5 app to version 7 and have hit an issue with some existing code that attempts to use a Buffer global.

The code in question comes from the [btoa](https://git.coolaj86.com/coolaj86/btoa.js/src/branch/master/index.js) library which makes use of the global.

In my migrated Angular 7 app, I am getting `ReferenceError: Buffer is not defined` and is being thrown when attempting to call the btoa function exported from this library.

This however works all fine in my Angular 5 app.

What could be going on here? I am assuming it has to do with a change in the angular CLI and maybe the way webpack is bundling somehow?

I saw a similar question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50371593/angular-6-uncaught-referenceerror-buffer-is-not-defined) talking about related issues, and one suggestion was to install the buffer package, which I tried, but it made no difference for my situation.

Thanks

Comment: have you tried adding `"node"` to your `tsconfig.json->compilerOptions->types` array?

Comment: Are you able to reproduce this error on stackblitz?

Comment: @PierreDuc - I tried that but it makes no difference. I didnt expect it to since I didnt have this in my tsconfig for my angular 5 version anyway. But thanks for the suggestion!

Comment: the btoa library you are referencing is for node.js. It uses the `Buffer` global which is only available inside `node`. Not in the browser. For proper compilation, you need to have the node js typings, and `node` inside your types array. If you do not run your application inside nodejs, you don't need the btoa package

Answer (score 27):

Angular ver 7.2

1. install buffer

$npm install buffer

2. install node

$npm i @types/node

3. then add 'node' to your tsconfig.app.json not tsconfig.json

   ```
    "compilerOptions": {
       "outDir": "../out-tsc/app",
       "module": "es2015",
       "types": ["node"]
     },
   ```

make sure

```
"typeRoots": [
  "node_modules/@types"
],
```

in your tsconfig.json

4.add global.Buffer to your polyfills.ts

```
(window as any).global = window;
(window as any).global.Buffer = (window as any).global.Buffer || require('buffer').Buffer;
```

Comment: It seems step 2 `$npm i @types/node` and 4 `(window as any).global = window;
(window as any).global.Buffer = (window as any).global.Buffer || require('buffer').Buffer;` of your guide are not necessary for **Ionic 4** with **Angular 8**.