# Use Cheerio in an Angular project

Tags: javascript, node.js, angular, cheerio

I've got an Angular web-scraping project that I'm trying to use Cheerio in. I have included Cheerio into my `angular.json` file. When I include Cheerio into my App component I get the following error message:

```
index.js:43 Uncaught ReferenceError: global is not defined
    at Object../node_modules/buffer/index.js (index.js:43)
    at __webpack_require__ (bootstrap:79)
    at Object../node_modules/readable-stream/node_modules/safe-buffer/index.js (index.js:2)
    at __webpack_require__ (bootstrap:79)
    at Object../node_modules/readable-stream/lib/_stream_readable.js (_stream_readable.js:55)
    at __webpack_require__ (bootstrap:79)
    at Object../node_modules/readable-stream/readable-browser.js (readable-browser.js:1)
    at __webpack_require__ (bootstrap:79)
    at Object../node_modules/stream-browserify/index.js (index.js:28)
    at __webpack_require__ (bootstrap:79)
```

I fixed this error by typing this into `index.html` as @Leandro Matilla suggested:

```
if (global === undefined) {
    var global = window;
}
```

But now I get a different error:

```
util.js:103 Uncaught ReferenceError: Buffer is not defined
    at Object../node_modules/core-util-is/lib/util.js (util.js:103)
    at __webpack_require__ (bootstrap:79)
    at Object../node_modules/readable-stream/lib/_stream_readable.js (_stream_readable.js:67)
    at __webpack_require__ (bootstrap:79)
    at Object../node_modules/readable-stream/readable-browser.js (readable-browser.js:1)
    at __webpack_require__ (bootstrap:79)
    at Object../node_modules/stream-browserify/index.js (index.js:28)
    at __webpack_require__ (bootstrap:79)
    at Object../node_modules/cheerio/node_modules/parse5/lib/parser/parser_stream.js (parser_stream.js:3)
    at __webpack_require__ (bootstrap:79)
```

How do I fix this error message? I've tried other solutions on StackOverflow, but none of them have worked...

Comment: "...Cheerio, an implementation of core jQuery designed specifically for the server." Why do you want to use a server lib in an Angular project?

Comment: @Phix Because I'm making a web scraper, and as far as my knowledge goes jQuery works on the current DOM, not provided data.

Comment: jQuery is a library to help with DOM manipulation, there's no DOM in node.  Scraping is done on the server.

Comment: You're getting the `Buffer` error because `Buffer` doesn't exist in the browser. **This package is designed to run in a NodeJS environment**.

Answer (score 0):

Add this to your `index.html`

```
<script>
    if (global === undefined) {
        var global = window;
    }
</script>
```

Comment: This solution fixed the first error, but now I get a different error (See my edited question).

Comment: install the buffer package using npm or yarn. And add the following into polyfills.ts ()

Comment: global.Buffer = global.Buffer || require('buffer').Buffer;

Comment: If the answer resolve the first problem, close the ask. And make one new

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50371593/angular-6-uncaught-referenceerror-buffer-is-not-defined

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't have to add it to angular.json. Here's how you should do it. Note: as @phix correctly points out, cheerio doesn't appear to be intended for front-end use. To that point, any manipulation you're attempting to do with cheerio can likely be done more clearly using Angular alone.

First, install it either with npm or yarn.

`npm install cheerio`

Then, add it to your component:

`import * as cheerio from 'cheerio';`

You should then be able to use it, like in the documentation:

```
const $ = cheerio.load('<ul id="fruits">...</ul>');
```

More examples of usage: https://www.npmjs.com/package/cheerio

Edit: As mentioned in the comments, it seems like cheerio relies on server side libraries. You need to switch to the Node framework to use this package. A guide on setting up Cheerio and Node: https://buttercms.com/blog/web-scraping-with-nodejs-and-cheerio

Comment: This solution doesn't work. I still get `global is not defined`.

Comment: @Xydez in the comments they correctly suggest using Nodejs. I would switch to Node for the framework. Selenium also works well as a scraper and would work with node or python. It would be unique to run a web scraper on the front end using something like an iframe, I've never seen that done. Best approach is server side, and, you will find lots of guides to help. Here's one for Node and cheerio: https://buttercms.com/blog/web-scraping-with-nodejs-and-cheerio