# Angular 10: Buffer is not defined

Tags: angular, amqp, node-amqp

I need some help cause I don't have any idea what to do. I have to use 'amqplib' in my Angular project. Firstly I have tried to use 'amqp-ts', but as soon as I've opened a browser I had an error:[image: Buffer is not defined]

After several tries, I have switched to 'amqplib'. However when I'm trying call library's functions I get an error:[image: Second error]

The error occurs in line:

```
if (Buffer.from && Buffer.alloc && Buffer.allocUnsafe && Buffer.allocUnsafeSlow) {
  module.exports = buffer
} else {
  // Copy properties from require('buffer')
  copyProps(buffer, exports)
  exports.Buffer = SafeBuffer
}
```

so again, Buffer is not defined.

I've tried several solutions mentioned here: [Angular 6 Uncaught ReferenceError: Buffer is not defined](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50371593/angular-6-uncaught-referenceerror-buffer-is-not-defined) and I have ended up with:
-installed 'buffer' package

-in polyfills.ts

```
declare var require: any;
declare var global: any;

(window as any).global = window;
// @ts-ignore
window.Buffer = window.Buffer || require('buffer').Buffer;
(window as any).process = {
  version: ''
};
```

-in index.html

```
<script>
    var global = global || window;
</script>
```

Nevertheless, none of them helped and still I have these errors :/

Answer (score 7):

I was trying to use crypto-browserify

I too ended up installing Buffer package using npm

then I was getting an error called  :- Buffer is not a constructor
here is what I did -

In polyfills.ts -

```
import * as Buffer from '../node_modules/buffer/index';
(window as any).global = window;
(window as any).process = {};
(window as any).process = window;
(window as any).process.browser = true;
(window as any).process.version = '';
(window as any).process.versions = { node: false };
(window as any).global.Buffer = Buffer.Buffer;
```

Answer (score 1):

I can't speak for previous versions of angular, but for **angular 11**. An elegant way to incorporate non-browser nodejs functions like buffer is to use webpack's polyfilling system

create a webpack.config.js file in the directory root and add these lines:

```
module.exports = {
  node: {
    Buffer: true
  }
};
```

then in you angular.json file, add the **extraWebpackConfig** option  under **build**, **test** and **serve** json settings

```
"architect": {
        "build": {
          "builder": "ngx-build-plus:browser",
          "options": {
            "extraWebpackConfig": "webpack.config.js",
```

more details here: [Buffer is not defined](https://github.com/isaacs/core-util-is/issues/27#issuecomment-652181111)

Comment: Not working for me, but I have a different builder `@angular-devkit/build-angular:browser`. This is in an ionic4-angular11 app, btw.