# Angular 7 Clarifai api "global is not defined at Object../node_modules/clarifai/dist/index.js"

Tags: angular, clarifai

i can't user clarifai in angular 7
give me this error

> index.js:8 Uncaught ReferenceError: global is not defined
>       at Object../node_modules/clarifai/dist/index.js (index.js:8)
>       at **webpack_require** (bootstrap:78)
>       at Module../src/app/home/home.component.ts (main.js:231)
>       at **webpack_require** (bootstrap:78)
>       at Module../src/app/app.module.ts (app.component.ts:8)
>       at **webpack_require** (bootstrap:78)
>       at Module../src/main.ts (main.ts:1)
>       at **webpack_require** (bootstrap:78)
>       at Object.0 (main.ts:12)
>       at **webpack_require** (bootstrap:78)

this index.js

> 'use strict';
>
> var App = require('./App');
>
> var _require = require('./../package.json'),
>       version = _require.version;
>
> module.exports = global.Clarifai = {   version: version,   App: App,
>   GENERAL_MODEL: 'aaa03c23b3724a16a56b629203edc62c',   FOOD_MODEL:
>   'bd367be194cf45149e75f01d59f77ba7',   TRAVEL_MODEL:
>   'eee28c313d69466f836ab83287a54ed9',   NSFW_MODEL:
>   'e9576d86d2004ed1a38ba0cf39ecb4b1',   WEDDINGS_MODEL:
>   'c386b7a870114f4a87477c0824499348',   WEDDING_MODEL:
>   'c386b7a870114f4a87477c0824499348',   COLOR_MODEL:
>   'eeed0b6733a644cea07cf4c60f87ebb7',   CLUSTER_MODEL:
>   'cccbe437d6e54e2bb911c6aa292fb072',   FACE_DETECT_MODEL:
>   'a403429f2ddf4b49b307e318f00e528b',   FOCUS_MODEL:
>   'c2cf7cecd8a6427da375b9f35fcd2381',   LOGO_MODEL:
>   'c443119bf2ed4da98487520d01a0b1e3',   DEMOGRAPHICS_MODEL:
>   'c0c0ac362b03416da06ab3fa36fb58e3',   GENERAL_EMBED_MODEL:
>   'bbb5f41425b8468d9b7a554ff10f8581',   FACE_EMBED_MODEL:
>   'd02b4508df58432fbb84e800597b8959',   APPAREL_MODEL:
>   'e0be3b9d6a454f0493ac3a30784001ff',   MODERATION_MODEL:
>   'd16f390eb32cad478c7ae150069bd2c6',   TEXTURES_AND_PATTERNS:
>   'fbefb47f9fdb410e8ce14f24f54b47ff',   LANDSCAPE_QUALITY:
>   'bec14810deb94c40a05f1f0eb3c91403',   PORTRAIT_QUALITY:
>   'de9bd05cfdbf4534af151beb2a5d0953' };

How can I fix this error

Comment: Looks like this answer is related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50356408/upgrading-to-angular-6-x-gives-uncaught-referenceerror-global-is-not-defined

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Upgrading to angular-6.x gives "Uncaught ReferenceError: global is not defined"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50356408/upgrading-to-angular-6-x-gives-uncaught-referenceerror-global-is-not-defined)

Answer (score 1):

put in  polyfills.ts

(window as any).global = window;