# Angular 7: Uncaught ReferenceError: global is not defined when adding package

Tags: node.js, angular, typescript, dragula, ng2-dragula

I am building an Angular 7 app, and when i add a package `npm install dragula --save` and import this into the `pollyfills.ts` file i get this error:

> index.js:2 Uncaught ReferenceError: global is not defined
>       at Object../node_modules/custom-event/index.js (index.js:2)
>       at **webpack_require** (bootstrap:83)
>       at Object../node_modules/crossvent/src/crossvent.js (crossvent.js:3)
>       at **webpack_require** (bootstrap:83)
>       at Object../node_modules/dragula/dragula.js (dragula.js:4)
>       at **webpack_require** (bootstrap:83)
>       at Module../src/polyfills.ts (polyfills.ts:1)
>       at **webpack_require** (bootstrap:83)
>       at Object.1 (polyfills.ts:92)
>       at **webpack_require** (bootstrap:83)

When I googled it everyone says to add this `(window as any).global = window;` to `pollyfills.ts` I have done this and I still get the error. I also ready to delete the node_modules folder and `npm i` I have done this as well.

I do not know what else to do here. can anyone please tell me some sugestions or at least explain why this would happen?

This may not be relevant but I'm going to add it as well. There is another error which wasnt there before I imported them into `pollyfills.ts`

> accordion-group.component.ts:9 Uncaught ReferenceError: global is not
>   defined
>       at Module../src/app/components/accordion/accordion-group.component.ts
>   (accordion-group.component.ts:9)
>       at **webpack_require** (bootstrap:83)
>       at Module../src/app/components/accordion/accordion.module.ts (accordion.component.ts:10)
>       at **webpack_require** (bootstrap:83)
>       at Module../src/app/shared/shared.module.ts (window.extensions.ts:15)
>       at **webpack_require** (bootstrap:83)
>       at Module../src/app/app.module.ts (app.constants.ts:17)
>       at **webpack_require** (bootstrap:83)
>       at Module../src/main.ts (main.ts:1)
>       at **webpack_require** (bootstrap:83)

Comment: It appears "dragula" needs a [angular polyfill](https://github.com/valor-software/ng2-dragula). Read [the docs](https://www.npmjs.com/package/dragula)

Comment: Isnt that what i'm doing when i do this `import 'dragula';` in `pollyfills.ts`

Comment: either way I'd advise for plugin like this your going to get a much better response raising an [issue on github](https://github.com/bevacqua/dragula) rather than here. There are so many plugins the chances of anyone knowing this particular one is slim

Comment: `npm install ng2-dragula` is how the polyfill says to install it. Like I said, I don't know this plugin so `¯\_(ツ)_/¯` also read the setup instructions

Comment: thank you, I will raise issue on github and post result here

Comment: What version of @angular/cli are you using?

Comment: I am using `"@angular/cli": "7.1.3",`

Comment: Try to update `npm install @angular/cli`, I am using `"@angular/cli": "~7.2.3",` and there are no errors

Comment: That did not do it

Comment: Check https://stackoverflow.com/a/57507470/11127383

Answer (score 70, accepted):

I had a similar problem few weeks ago, and I solve it when I change few setts in polyfills.ts now It look like:

```
/**
 * This file includes polyfills needed by Angular and is loaded before the app.
 * You can add your own extra polyfills to this file.
 *
 * This file is divided into 2 sections:
 *   1. Browser polyfills. These are applied before loading ZoneJS and are sorted by browsers.
 *   2. Application imports. Files imported after ZoneJS that should be loaded before your main
 *      file.
 *
 * The current setup is for so-called "evergreen" browsers; the last versions of browsers that
 * automatically update themselves. This includes Safari >= 10, Chrome >= 55 (including Opera),
 * Edge >= 13 on the desktop, and iOS 10 and Chrome on mobile.
 *
 * Learn more in https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/browser-support.html
 */

/***************************************************************************************************
 * BROWSER POLYFILLS
 */

/** IE9, IE10 and IE11 requires all of the following polyfills. **/
// import 'core-js/es6/symbol';
// import 'core-js/es6/object';
// import 'core-js/es6/function';
// import 'core-js/es6/parse-int';
// import 'core-js/es6/parse-float';
// import 'core-js/es6/number';
// import 'core-js/es6/math';
// import 'core-js/es6/string';
// import 'core-js/es6/date';
// import 'core-js/es6/array';
// import 'core-js/es6/regexp';
// import 'core-js/es6/map';
// import 'core-js/es6/weak-map';
// import 'core-js/es6/set';

/** IE10 and IE11 requires the following for NgClass support on SVG elements */
// import 'classlist.js';  // Run `npm install --save classlist.js`.

/** IE10 and IE11 requires the following for the Reflect API. */
// import 'core-js/es6/reflect';


/** Evergreen browsers require these. **/
// Used for reflect-metadata in JIT. If you use AOT (and only Angular decorators), you can remove.
import 'core-js/es7/reflect';


/**
 * Required to support Web Animations `@angular/platform-browser/animations`.
 * Needed for: All but Chrome, Firefox and Opera. http://caniuse.com/#feat=web-animation
 **/
import 'web-animations-js';  // Run `npm install --save web-animations-js`.

/**
 * By default, zone.js will patch all possible macroTask and DomEvents
 * user can disable parts of macroTask/DomEvents patch by setting following flags
 */

 // (window as any).__Zone_disable_requestAnimationFrame = true; // disable patch requestAnimationFrame
 // (window as any).__Zone_disable_on_property = true; // disable patch onProperty such as onclick
 // (window as any).__zone_symbol__BLACK_LISTED_EVENTS = ['scroll', 'mousemove']; // disable patch specified eventNames

 /*
 * in IE/Edge developer tools, the addEventListener will also be wrapped by zone.js
 * with the following flag, it will bypass `zone.js` patch for IE/Edge
 */
// (window as any).__Zone_enable_cross_context_check = true;

/***************************************************************************************************
 * Zone JS is required by default for Angular itself.
 */
import 'zone.js/dist/zone';  // Included with Angular CLI.



/***************************************************************************************************
 * APPLICATION IMPORTS
 */

(window as any)['global'] = window;
```

Try with this setts and let me know.

Look also in your `app.module.ts` - did you import Dragula in good way?

```
@NgModule({
    declarations: [
        ...
    ],
    imports: [
        ...
        DragulaModule.forRoot(),
        ...
    ],
    exports: [
        ...
    ],
    providers: [
       ...    ],
    bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
```

Please note that this should be a main `app.module.ts` for your app, not any child or lazy loaded module.

Answer (score 77):

It could be also resolved by adding

```
(window as any).global = window;
```

to your `polyfills.ts` .

Ref: https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/issues/9827#issuecomment-386154063

Comment: This worked for me when using sha.js library with angular 11

Comment: polyfills.ts is not available in my angular project .

Answer (score 18):

In my vision the best solution is to add this code in your index.html for testing

```
<script>
  if (global === undefined) {
    var global = window;
  }
</script>
```

And this code to build for production (install domino ... with npm install first)

```
const domino = require('domino');
const fs = require('fs');
const path = require('path');
const template = fs
  .readFileSync(path.join('dist/browser', 'index.html'))
  .toString();
const window = domino.createWindow(template);

// Ignite UI browser objects abstractions
(global as any).window = window;
(global as any).document = window.document;
(global as any).Event = window.Event;
(global as any).KeyboardEvent = window.KeyboardEvent;
(global as any).MouseEvent = window.MouseEvent;
(global as any).FocusEvent = window.FocusEvent;
(global as any).PointerEvent = window.PointerEvent;
(global as any).HTMLElement = window.HTMLElement;
(global as any).HTMLElement.prototype.getBoundingClientRect = () => {
    return {
      left: '',
      right: '',
      top: '',
      bottom: ''
  };
};

// If using IgxIconService to register icons
(global as any).XMLHttpRequest = require('xmlhttprequest').XMLHttpRequest;

// Other optional depending on your application configuration
(global as any).object = window.object;
(global as any).navigator = window.navigator;
(global as any).localStorage = window.localStorage;
(global as any).DOMTokenList = window.DOMTokenList;
```

Comment: In my opinion its also a good answer, but I always avoid changing anything in `index.html` file.

Comment: This to me is the cleanest approach, without messing with the polyfills or whatever. @kris_IV You'll change the polyfills, but not an html index file? Interesting

Comment: Yes, please look on this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/54352978/2972087 @KhoPhi

Answer (score 2):

I got the same issue in one of my angular project and I tried few things. At last I was able to solve the issue . We just need to add one line of code in index.html file . Check the code below .

```
<!-- your index.html -->
<script>

var global = global || window
</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

Do you have custom `webpack` configuration for browser? Most probably declared in `angular.json` like so:

```
...
"build": {
  "builder": "@angular-builders/custom-webpack:browser",
  "options": {
    "customWebpackConfig": {
    "path": "./webpack.browser.config.js"
  },
  ...
```

Then `webpack.browser.config.js` might look like so:

```
const dotenv = require("dotenv-webpack");
const webpackConfig = {
  node: { global: true, fs: "empty" }, // Fix: "Uncaught ReferenceError: global is not defined", and "Can't resolve 'fs'".
  output: {
    libraryTarget: "umd", // Fix: "Uncaught ReferenceError: exports is not defined".
  },
  plugins: [new dotenv()],
  target: "node",
};

module.exports = webpackConfig; // Export all custom Webpack configs.
```

Remove from its config `target: "node"` - it solves the problem.

Comment: removing node worked for me, I was copying the webpack config file from another node package ^^

Comment: @MuhammedMoussa if it worked out, please upvote for the other code fellows ;)

Answer (score 1):

I also got "global not defined" error. All I had to do is add

```
<script>
  global = globalThis // fix for "global not defined" error
</script>
```

to the \src\index.html (angular's main HTML file). But it was different package and I got the error in the browser console, so this might not help.