# How can I use csv-parse in Angular?

Tags: angular

I was using [csv-parse](https://www.npmjs.com/package/csv-parse) succesfully in a Vue project.
The code looks like this:

```
import * as csvParse from 'csv-parse';
const parse = require('csv-parse')

const parseOptions: csvParse.Options = {
    //options here...
};

var parser: csvParse.Parser = csvParse(parseOptions, function(data, err) {
    console.log(data);
}) as csvParse.Parser;

const parseCallback:csvParse.Callback = (err: Error|undefined, records: any, info: csvParse.Info) => 
{
    //code to run after parse...
};
parse(csvText, parseOptions, parseCallback);
```

We switched to Angular 8 and the same code started raising this error:

```
index.js:43 Uncaught ReferenceError: global is not defined
    at Object../node_modules/buffer/index.js (index.js:43)
    at __webpack_require__ (bootstrap:79)
    at Object../node_modules/safe-buffer/index.js (index.js:2)
    at __webpack_require__ (bootstrap:79)
    at Object../node_modules/readable-stream/lib/_stream_readable.js (_stream_readable.js:55)
    at __webpack_require__ (bootstrap:79)
    at Object../node_modules/readable-stream/readable-browser.js (readable-browser.js:1)
    at __webpack_require__ (bootstrap:79)
    at Object../node_modules/stream-browserify/index.js (index.js:28)
    at __webpack_require__ (bootstrap:79)
```

I added

```
declare function require(path: string): any;
```

to handle require in typescript.
I also tried removing the require. I get the same error.

How can I fix this? Thanks.

Comment: Just use the `csvParse` variable ?

Comment: I get the same error

Answer (score 0):

After installing the `csv-parse` you can change the `polyfills.ts` and add this line of code:

```
(window as any)['global'] = window;
```

Then in your `app.module.ts`, try to import the `CSV` module:

```
@NgModule({
    declarations: [
        ...
    ],
    imports: [
        ...
        CSVModule.forRoot(),
        ...
    ],
    exports: [
        ...
    ],
    providers: [
       ...    ],
    bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
```

Here's a related [SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54349858/angular-7-uncaught-referenceerror-global-is-not-defined-when-adding-package/54352978).

EDITED

Regarding the error you encoutered, try to add this inside the polyfills.ts:

```
// @ts-ignore
window.Buffer = window.Buffer || require('buffer').Buffer;
```

This should solve your problem.

Comment: After adding the polyfill I get this error:
util.js:103 Uncaught ReferenceError: Buffer is not defined
at Object../node_modules/core-util-is/lib/util.js (util.js:103)

Comment: If I add the polyfill for Buffer I get an error about process, then about slice...

Comment: Then I will recommend to use [`angular-csv-prser`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/angular-csv-parser).

Comment: Thank you. I was also looking for an alternative. I found https://www.npmjs.com/package/papaparse