# How to fix "ReferenceError: exports is not defined" in a pure TypeScript project?

Tags: javascript, typescript

If I write a .ts with any kind of import or export instruction the resulting .js will generate the following error when loaded in an HTML page:  "ReferenceError: exports is not defined"

#### How to reproduce:

1. Create a Blank Node.js web application project in VS
2. Add a .ts with an import or export line
3. Add some HTML calling the resulting .js
4. Start an HTTP server (`http-server -g [port]`) and reach your HTML

I tried:

- Targeting ES5
- Removing the line `"module": "commonjs"` from tsconfig.json`
- Installing CommonJS and SystemJS
- Compiling the .ts using `tsc`
- Any other solution Stack Overflow has in similar questions
- All the possible permutations of the above.

My .ts (can be anything if it has an import instruction):

```
import { setTimeout } from "timers";
setTimeout(() => console.log("asdf"), 1000);
```

The HTML just has a simple body referencing the script

### `package.json`

```
{
  "name": "nodejs-web-app4",
  "version": "0.0.0",
  "description": "NodejsWebApp4",
  "main": "server.js",
  "author": {
    "name": ""
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@types/node": "^8.0.14"
  }
}
```

### `tsconfig.json`

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "module": "commonjs",
    "target": "es6",
    "lib": ["es6"],
    "sourceMap": true
  },
  "exclude": [
    "node_modules"
  ]
}
```

#### Resulting .js:

From VS build (results in `ReferenceError: exports is not defined`):

```
"use strict";
Object.defineProperty(exports, "__esModule", { value: true });
const timers_1 = require("timers");
timers_1.setTimeout(() => console.log("asdf"), 1000);
//# sourceMappingURL=home-script.js.map
```

From command `tsc [filename].ts` (results in `ReferenceError: exports is not defined`):

```
"use strict";
exports.__esModule = true;
var timers_1 = require("timers");
timers_1.setTimeout(function () { return console.log("asdf"); }, 1000);
```

From VS Build but removing `"module": "commonjs"` from tsconfig (results in `SyntaxError: import declarations may only appear at top level of a module`):

```
import { setTimeout } from "timers";
setTimeout(() => console.log("asdf"), 1000);
//# sourceMappingURL=asdf.js.map
```

All the HTML and ts will be called as "static" (no MVC)

Is it wrong to use `http-server` to see static HTML from my VS project? Is that the issue?

Should build any other way? Use a different setup?

I have a workaround (i.e., keep everything I need in the same TypeScript file), but it confuses me that I can't create and visualize a simple project with Node/TS.

Comment: Check https://stackoverflow.com/a/57507470/11127383

Answer (score 29, accepted):

Browsers don't support *commonjs* modules. You will need to use some tool (webpack, rollup, browserify) to bundle your modules after compilation.

If you remove the *module* option in the *tsconfig.json* or if you set to *es2015* or *esnext*, the **import** and **export** statements will remain as they were in the original file.

```
import { foo } from './bar.js';

export default class Baz {}
```

It could work because some browsers already support native [ES modules](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/import) but it is necessary to add to the script tag a **type** attribute and set it to *module*.

```
<script type="module" src="foo.js"></script>
```

If you don't, you'll get some error like the '*SyntaxError: import declarations may only appear at top level of a module*' one.

Comment: Removing `CommonJs` and adding `type="module"` worked, but most important, now I get what was happening.Thank you for the explanation.

Comment: I stumbled a similar issue which I didn't remove `"module"` in `tsconfig.json` file.  Setting `"module": "es2015"` and adding `type="module"` attribute in `script` tag does the trick for me.