# typescript exports bug keeping me from running code properly

Tags: javascript, typescript, tsc

I'm learning typescript and every time i compile my project typescript adds this to my .js file

```
exports.__esModule = true;
```

This is apparently essential to the program if i am importing anything. But my browser says

```
Uncaught ReferenceError: exports is not defined
```

Why is this happening, I have tried defining it by creating a dummy var exports variable but then it tells me __esmodule cant edit property of undefined.

At this point typescript has made my project take much longer then its advertised rating of making projects quicker. I am about to give up and use regular javascript.

app.ts

```
import {privateRoom} from './room';

let socket : any = io();
function createRoomWithYoutubeID() {

    const youtubeVideo : string = (<HTMLInputElement>document.getElementById('link_input')).value;
    socket.emit('create_room', youtubeVideo);

}


console.log(privateRoom());
```

app.js

```
"use strict";
exports.__esModule = true;
var room_1 = require("./room");
var socket = io();
function createRoomWithYoutubeID() {
    var youtubeVideo = document.getElementById('link_input').value;
    socket.emit('create_room', youtubeVideo);
}
console.log(room_1.privateRoom());
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to fix "ReferenceError: exports is not defined" in a pure TypeScript project?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54670544/how-to-fix-referenceerror-exports-is-not-defined-in-a-pure-typescript-project)

Comment: Don't give up!! It's a bit hard at first but trust me, once you've gone through that, you will never want to return to plain JS.

Comment: Hey Joseph, unfortunately it does not. I'm about to add my code incase that helps