# Pure TypeScript - “ReferenceError: exports is not defined”

Tags: typescript

I have a simple client-server typescript application and every import statement in my client.ts file will result in the `ReferenceError: exports is not defined` in browser after loading the HTML.
project structure:

```
root
|-- dist
    |-- public
        |-- client.js
        |-- client.js.map
    |-- src
        |-- index.js
        |-- index.js.map
|-- node_modules
|-- public
    |-- client.ts
|-- src
    |-- index.ts
|-- index.html
|-- package.json
|-- tsconfig.json
```

I've read every similar question like this one [How to fix "ReferenceError: exports is not defined" in a pure TypeScript project?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54670544/how-to-fix-referenceerror-exports-is-not-defined-in-a-pure-typescript-project) and tried everything they suggested but still no luck!

`Index.ts`

```
import express from "express";
import path from "path";
import http from "http";
import {Server, Socket} from "socket.io";

const app = express();
const server = http.createServer(app);
const io = new Server(server);

// set static folder
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, '../../')));

io.on('connection', (socket: Socket) => {
  console.log('new ws connection');
});

const port = 8080 || process.env.PORT; // default port to listen

// start the Express server
server.listen(port, () => {
  console.log(`server started at http://localhost:${port}`);
});
```

`client.ts`

```
import { io, Socket } from "socket.io-client";
const socket: Socket = io();
```

`package.json`

```
{
  "name": "proto",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "main": "dist/index.js",
  "scripts": {
    "start": "node dist/src/index.js"
  },
  "keywords": [],
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC",
  "devDependencies": {
    "@types/express": "^4.17.13",
    "@types/node": "^16.3.3",
    "tslint": "^5.12.1",
    "typescript": "^3.9.10"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "express": "^4.17.1",
    "socket.io": "^4.1.3",
    "socket.io-client": "^4.1.3",
  }
}
```

`tsconfig.json`

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "module": "commonjs",
    "esModuleInterop": true,
    "allowSyntheticDefaultImports": true,
    "target": "es6",
    "noImplicitAny": true,
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "sourceMap": true,
    "outDir": "dist",
    "baseUrl": ".",
    "paths": {
      "*": [
        "*",
        "src/*",
        "public/*"
      ]
    }
  },
  "lib": [
    "es2015"
  ]
}
```

`client.js` result from `tsc` compile output:

```
"use strict";
Object.defineProperty(exports, "__esModule", { value: true });
const socket_io_client_1 = require("socket.io-client");
const socket = socket_io_client_1.io();
//# sourceMappingURL=client.js.map
```

Error message in browser console:
`Uncaught ReferenceError: exports is not defined at client.js:2`

Comment: Yep, you need to bundle (pack all files together) your code if you want to deliver it in browser. Or use module system, but this is out of the scope of the question. The easies way to bundle is to use something like parcel. It will do all the job for you

Comment: Use [Webpack](https://webpack.js.org/guides/typescript/), it helps typescript for exports

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is that for the browser, you need to bundle (pack all files together) you code.

To achieve this you may use [parcel](https://parceljs.org/), [webpack](https://webpack.js.org/) or [browserify](https://browserify.org/)

The simplest way (for me) is to use parcel. Simply install it as dev dependency

```
npm i parcel -D
```

And add build command to the package.json

```json
...
"build": "parcel index.html"
...
```

And reference your root `ts` file from the index.html.
Might happen you will be prompted to move index.html to the `src` folder

Everything other, including hot module reloading, minification and hashing parcel will do for you.

The documentation for Parcel is [here](https://parceljs.org/typeScript.html)

If you want something more flexible, then webpack should be your choice. Webpack is something like Swiss Knife in the world of bundling, it's really cool, but sometimes a bit complicated.

P.S. If you want to take a look at something newer - [vite](https://vitejs.dev/) is also an option

Comment: Thanks a lot, that worked!
but I'm still wondering about the source of the problem and why can't we use pure ts without a bundler?

Comment: @Omid The short answer - because browser doesn't have `require` function from this line of code `const socket_io_client_1 = require("socket.io-client");`  The long  answer is that actually browser can work without bundling, when working with modules
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Modules