# aws-amplify js to angular app has error: global is not defined

Tags: angular, amazon-cognito, aws-amplify

I am testing AWS Amplify from Angular to Cognito User Pool following:

https://docs.amplify.aws/lib/restapi/getting-started/q/platform/js

The Angular app has successfully compiled however the exception throws out in the Chrome console:

```
index.js:43 Uncaught ReferenceError: global is not defined
at Object../node_modules/buffer/index.js (index.js:43)
at __webpack_require__ (bootstrap:84)
at Module../node_modules/amazon-cognito-identity-js/es/AuthenticationHelper.js (AuthenticationHelper.js:1)
at __webpack_require__ (bootstrap:84)
at Module../node_modules/amazon-cognito-identity-js/es/index.js (index.js:1)
at __webpack_require__ (bootstrap:84)
at Module../node_modules/@aws-amplify/auth/lib-esm/Auth.js (Auth.js:1)
at __webpack_require__ (bootstrap:84)
at Module../node_modules/@aws-amplify/auth/lib-esm/index.js (index.js:1)
at __webpack_require__ (bootstrap:84)
```

ANy idea please?

Answer (score 25):

[this suggestion works in this case as well.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50356408/upgrading-to-angular-6-x-gives-uncaught-referenceerror-global-is-not-defined)

```
<script>
    var global = global || window;
    var Buffer = Buffer || [];
    var process = process || {
      env: { DEBUG: undefined },
      version: []
    };
  </script>
```

or add to the end of `polyfills.ts`

```
(window as any).global = window;
(window as any).process = {
  env: { DEBUG: undefined },
};
```

Answer (score 14):

The AWS docs suggest adding

```
(window as any).global = window;

(window as any).process = {
  env: { DEBUG: undefined },
};
```

to `src/polyfills.ts`

This has worked in my projects.

https://docs.amplify.aws/start/getting-started/data-model/q/integration/ionic#connect-frontend-to-api

Comment: I'm getting this error in svelte-kit too

Answer (score 4):

I had a chance to fix this issue by adding the below code to index.html file header section.

```
<head>
<script>
  if (global === undefined) {
    var global = window;
  }
</script>
</head>
```

Comment: Mate, thanks a ton for this. But, do you know why this works?
Amplify - vanilla JS - Node.js etc. etc. etc. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

In my case, it was failing when running `npm test`. So I had to add the following to `test.ts` after the imports.

**test.ts**

```
(window as any).global = window;
```